# Issue with Fancy Tree rendering on IE if server Name/IP is used

Tags: jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, fancytree

I am facing issue with rendering of Fancy Tree. If I use server name/ip in the url the rendering gets messed up. This happens in IE only. I checked  on Chrome it's working fine. Would have asked the clients to use Chrome if I can :(.

Basically if I use the url as **http://localhost:9080/myapp**, the tree renders perfectly fine. 
But if I use the url as **http://114.112.23.45:9080/myapp**, or **http://MyServerName.sroot.net:9080/myapp**, the tree gets distorted.

Any thoughts !!

**Image in IE**

[image: Image in IE]

**Image in Chrome**

[image: Image in Chrome]

**UPDATE**

When I checked the console as suggested, I can see this code getting appending in my JSP which causes the error.

```
$('#listTree').tree({
    onLoadSuccess: function(node, data){
        alert('Data in listTree: '+data);  // alert node text property when clicked
    }
});
```

This is causing an error: *Object doesn't support property or method 'tree'.*

Comment: If you look in the console do you see any errors or any files that are not being loaded? Is the localhost set to different security restrictions?

Comment: Checked the console. It seems like a function gets added for the tree for 'onLoadSuccess'. This is causing an error: "Object doesn't support property or method 'tree'".

Comment: The issue is resolved now. Was the issue with IE setting. Please see the updated solution in Post itself.

Answer (score 0):

Were able to fix. We have to change the compatibility settings for IE as below:

Goto tools -> Compatibility View Settings -> below window will appear. Uncheck the highlighted box and restart IE.   (IE version 11, steps may be different in other version)

[image]